# Is there a fullrange argument for ggeffects::ggpredict

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression

I would like to get a plot like `ggplot2::geom_smooth(method = "lm", fullrange = T)` with  `ggeffects::ggpredict()`. The fit should only span the data and not the whole plot.

Can somebody help?

**Example**

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- mutate(mtcars, cyl = as_factor(cyl))
```

`ggplot2` with `fullrange = F`

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, group = cyl, color = cyl)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(method = "lm", fullrange = F)
```

`ggeffects` where `fullrange = F` is not possible

```
m <- lm(mpg ~ wt * cyl, data = mtcars)
data_m <- ggeffects::ggpredict(m, terms = c("wt", "cyl"))
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = cyl)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = data_m, aes(x = x, y = predicted, group = group, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), alpha = .3) +
  geom_line(data = data_m, aes(x = x, y = predicted, color = group))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `limit.range`?

```r
library(ggeffects)
data(iris)
m <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Species * Sepal.Length, data = iris)
ggpredict(m, c("Sepal.Length", "Species")) |> plot(add.data = TRUE)
#> Loading required namespace: ggplot2
```

[image]

```r
ggpredict(m, c("Sepal.Length", "Species")) |> plot(add.data = TRUE, limit.range = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I guess now, that a fullrange argument is not possible for the code of my question because of the separation of data (mtcars) and predictions (data_m).